# Java: Updating GUI element during timed loop

Tags: java, user-interface, timer, synthesizer

At home, expanding on a class assignment from this winter, trying to get it to **update a GUI element during run time** in order to show progress thought he loop.

Intended functionality is that, as it goes through a string, processing each char, a JLable that's been passed in from the GUI class **updates on each loop iteration** to show progress through the String. However, what happens is it only changes what's displayed on the label **after** the loop, after the final **Thread.sleep(1000)** expires (I don't know if it's before or after the synthesizer closes, don't think it would be related :/ ).

At this point, I'd like advice on how to get the JLabel 'progress' to change to the "Should show" text before the loop expires - some code unrelated to my problem has been removed to protect the efficient.

```
import javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem;
import javax.sound.midi.Synthesizer;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiChannel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class SoundPlayer {

 /*Deceleration of private variables for the class*/

/*Constructor that assighns variables and triggers doPlay()method. 
There is a reference to the JLabel 'Progress' passed in and declared beforehand, 
 so there is access.*/
}

public void doPlay() {
    int totalSound;
    playNumTimes = 1;
    defaultTime = true;
    sound = 0;
    extraSound = 0;

    try {   //Opens ability to play the music.
        Synthesizer synth = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
        synth.open();       //Will likely play sound, so opens channel.
        MidiChannel[] channels = synth.getChannels();

        musicNotes += ".";  //illegal character will mark end of string to play.

        //Examines each char of the String and acts accordingly.
        for (count = 0; count < musicNotes.length(); count++) { //For each char in the input.

            if (processChar(musicNotes.charAt(count))) { //If processed char is illegal and triggers a sound, play it!
                totalSound = extraSound + sound;    //Combines from given note and the < and >s.


                progress.setText("Should show");

                //PLAYS SOUND HERE!
                channels[channel].noteOn(totalSound, volume);
                Thread.sleep(300 * playNumTimes);   //Plays sound a number times equal to times.
                channels[channel].noteOff(totalSound);

                //After plays, resets values.
                playNumTimes = 1;
                defaultTime = true;
                sound = 0;      //Sound of 0 used to indicate no char has been assigned to the sound.
            }
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000);     //Wards against synthesizer from being closed prematurely and cutting off sound.
        synth.close();  //Closes after loop is finished.
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `doPlay`? If you're calling it on the Event Dispatch Thread, then that's your problem: you're preventing Swing from rendering what it needs to render (since rendering is also performed on the EDT). You might wanna look into [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)

Comment: @VinceEmigh: No, don't use a SwingWorker, just use a Swing Timer since all you're doing is trying to inject a little delay in the action.